# How I know if two sub-images of the base image fit (make up puzzle)?

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing

I have the base 1280x720 image. It's split into 8 equals rectangles. The sub-images are messed up and I need to solve this 'puzzle'. How can I detect if two sub-images fit?

I understand that I should use border pixels and compare them. And if two border pixels are similar then the sub-images fit. But in which way? How can I calculate the all image's border pixels in one coefficient or something like that?

I think I can just calculate the average color value for each border. This can be done by summing up the color values of all pixels along the border and dividing by the number of pixels. But is it ok?

Will be thankful for any advice.

Comment: What is enough for your puzzle depends on your puzzle. But simply trying with SAD(Sum of absolute differences) etc at first will be recommended to grasp the difficult point of the you puzzle.

Comment: @fana thank you, I decided to use Euclid's distance:  `sqrt [(im1.getRed - im2.getRed)^2 + (im1.getGreen - im2.getGreen)^2 + (im1.getBlue() - im2.getBlue)^2]` 
works perfectly for me